# How to update 2 divs with 1 ajax response?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a `signin()` button, and i want to use ajax so by clicking it it will update two divs: one will say "Welcome /your name/", and the other should print out some statistics table (in another place). The signing in itself and the welcome message are generated by a function called `signin()`. The table is generated by a function called `statistics_table()`.

And I have this in my button form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="return signin(); return statistics_table();"/>
```

But of course it's not working, because it returns the first function, and the operation is done. And both of the functions include a return statement inside them. How can I make the button call the 2 functions though?

I tried to put a call to the 2nd function just in the end of the 1st (before the return statement), but it also made some problems.

Comment: Instead of using an inline onclick handler, do it in the javascript. And then call the two functions in your onclick handler.

Comment: What do you mean by "do it in the javascript" ?

Comment: `object.onclick = function(){ signin(); statistics_table(); };`

Comment: Mybe you can wrap them into a third function. `function thirdFunction() { signin(); statistics_table();}` and in the onclick atribute: `onclick="return thirdFunction();"`. Is it working?

Comment: @FoPi No, because they both have a `return` inside them.

Comment: @McMastermind I don't quite get it... `object.onclick` should be written inside the `button form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe there is a relation between the two functions , try maybe to use different names of variables in the two functions .
if problem wasn't solved try to create a new function that calls both of them.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to both your functions to be called do not use `return` keyword:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick=signin();statistics_table();"/>
```

otherwise it would just call the first one.

The point is it is like a function body, if you do :

```
function clickHandler(){
    return signin();
    return statistics_table();
}
```

only the first line would be called, then you should do:

```
function clickHandler(){
    signin();
    statistics_table();
}
```

Comment: Is this prevent the default behavior (input submit)?

Comment: @FoPi: no,it just gets called just before the form gets submitted.